# Springboot application dependencies class data/jpa/EntityManagerFactoryDependsOnPostProcesso cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

I have sample Spring Boot application, with Gradle I was able to compile it. but while running its giving the below error message.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/jpa/EntityManagerFactoryDependsOnPostProcessor.class]
> cannot be opened because it does not exist

```
2022-07-07 21:56:29.747 DEBUG 20120 --- [restartedMain] com.usbank.appfit.Application            : Running with Spring Boot v2.7.0, Spring v5.3.20 
2022-07-07 21:56:29.747  INFO 20120 --- [restartedMain] com.usbank.appfit.Application            : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default" 
2022-07-07 21:56:29.821  INFO 20120 --- [restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable 
2022-07-07 21:56:29.822  INFO 20120 --- [restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG' 
2022-07-07 21:56:30.898  WARN 20120 --- [restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [org.springframework.boot.devtools.autoconfigure.DevToolsDataSourceAutoConfiguration]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/jpa/EntityManagerFactoryDependsOnPostProcessor.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist 
2022-07-07 21:56:30.918  INFO 20120 --- [restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 
2022-07-07 21:56:30.986 ERROR 20120 --- [restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [org.springframework.boot.devtools.autoconfigure.DevToolsDataSourceAutoConfiguration]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/jpa/EntityManagerFactoryDependsOnPostProcessor.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:610)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:311)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:600)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.access$800(ConfigurationClassParser.java:111)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.lambda$processGroupImports$1(ConfigurationClassParser.java:812)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:809)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:780)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:193)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/jpa/EntityManagerFactoryDependsOnPostProcessor.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:199)
```

Using below `build.gradle` file.

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'war'
}

 

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.3.10.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.3.10.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.3.10.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.3.10.RELEASE'
    implementation 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.200'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:2.3.10.RELEASE'   
    testImplementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.7'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.3.10.RELEASE'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.4.0'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.4.0'
}
```

May I know which dependencies need to be included to resolve this error?

Thanks

Comment: How did you build it and how are you running it? Also your logging `Running with Spring Boot v2.7.0, Spring v5.3.20 ` doesn't match with your dependencies. So you are probably not using gradle to build the war/jar you are running and manually messed around with dependencies.

Comment: converted from maven to gradle, thats how I got this file. removed version numbers from dependencies, its working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `org.springframework.boot` gradle plugin you don't need to specify most of the versions of the dependencies used by Spring Boot since the plugin manages them for you:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'com.h2database:h2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'   
    testImplementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine'
}
```

The versions of those dependencies will be set according to the `org.springframework.boot` plugin version used which in your case is **2.7.0**:

> Running with Spring Boot v2.7.0, Spring v5.3.20

The plugin version is generally specified like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.0'
}
```

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/ for more info.